# finding correct maven dependency of hazelcast, spring and hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, hazelcast

I am trying to integrate hazel cast and hibernate in a spring application. I intend to use hazelcast as 2nd level cache for hibernate.

I am using hazelcast 2.4 and hibernate 4.1. The spring version is 3.1. How do I correctly find the dependencies and their correct version. I have spent some time to get that right and and I will figure that out in some time. But what is the best way to figure that out.

Comment: Perhaps not a direct answer to your question, why are you using Hazelcast 2.4? If you don't want to use Hazelcast 3(.1), then at least use 2.6.5.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing is probably to make a Maven project that includes the versions of the libraries that you think you need and then use:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

to print out what everything has actually been resolved to. Then you can look through that and search for “surprising” variations. (An example is in the Maven [dependency plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html).)
Once you've identified a clash, you resolve it by defining which dependency to use in a `<dependencyManagement>` section. Mostly this is easy, but sometimes it isn't.

Some IDEs may have support for doing this dependency resolution process — I know that Eclipse does —  and that can make it substantially easier than doing it manually.